# Trying to shrink Windows C drive for partioning results in heavy restriction on the shrink amount

Tags: windows-10, partitioning

I am getting a similar issue to this post here: [Link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance-winpc/windows-disk-management-unable-to-shrink-c-drive/217c3521-b254-4662-bac9-bc90dc633fab)

However, unlike that post where they where couldn't shrink at all because available space was 0. I'm having an issue where there *is some* available space but only a tiny amount compared to how much is actually unused.
I also tried the post's answer/solution shown here:

> The reason why Windows won’t let you shrink the volume is as the
> message shown in Disk Management suggested, because there are
> immovable system files at the very end of the volume, as this
> screenshot from utility shows us. there are multiple things you could
> try to work this around.
>
> 1. Run the Disk Cleanup Wizard, making sure to remove the hibernation file and all restore points.
> 2. Disable System Restore
> 3. Disable the pagefile ( Open up System in Control Panel, then Advanced System Settings \ Advanced \ Performance \ Advanced \ Change
>    \ No Paging File.
> 4. Disable kernel memory dump. In the same Advanced Settings, go to Startup and Recovery \ Settings and then change the Write debugging
>    information drop-down to “None” to disable the kernel memory dump.
> 5. Disable Hibernation mode in your power options \ advanced power options screen.
>    Reboot the machine, and then delete your
>    c:\pagefile.sys file, following these instructions if you are having
>    issues. details about the fix and cause of this problem, see shrink
>    volume not enough space

Yet this did not work and still results in my error being present.
The screenshot below shows that I am only able to shrink my 952GB available space by a tiny 152GB. Which leaves the C drive with way too much space (822GB). Which only leaves 152GB of unallocated drive space to partition to another drive.

What I would like, is to shrink the C drive by at least 700GB which would result in the C drive being left which a more manageable 250GB. Thus 700GB total unallocated drive space to partition to other drives.

[image: My issue]

One important note that I'm not sure has any connection to this issue, but I have docker setup on my machine and was wondering if its internal systems are somehow holding all this extra space hostage in allocated memory.

Comment: You have to identify the unmovable files. Make sure Docker isn’t running and only then defrag your system

Comment: I've tried that as well. Docker is not running and all images and containers are deleted and not running at all.

Comment: @Ramhound is there a specific way to identify the unmovable files at the end of the drive so I can remove them?

Comment: The only way I know is to use a third-party application designed to defrag your system.  This will identify what files each block contains.  If you have an ssd you obviously can only perform an analysis of the drive.

Comment: I use a third party disk management tool, make the bootable usb, boot from it and shrink the partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a very similar issue, and ended up using an application called [AOMEI Partition Assistant](https://www.diskpart.com/).

For whatever reason, disk management just could not shrink it properly, and after about an hour of researching, I came across this app.

I can definitely vouch for it, as I can now run a triple-boot system on my PC, it's much better than disk management.

Comment: Well.... crap.... Even this application fails to shrink/split my partition. The options are just grayed out and when running some scans with the app, it just says everything is fine. I also tried optimising and defragging my drive and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I'm marking your comment as the solution because I did end up using a third-party partitioning assistant. The real issue was ESET security had unmovable security files sitting at the end of the disk drive. I had to uninstall ESET, partition my drives and reinstall ESET for it work.

Comment: Good to hear you got it working! :)